# what is the difference between render() and drupal_render()?

Tags: theming

what is the difference between `render()` and `drupal_render()` anyway ?
Is there a reason to use only drupal_render()?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The docs for `render()` explain it pretty well:

> This function renders an element using drupal_render(). The top level element is shown with show() before rendering, so it will always be rendered even if hide() had been previously used on it.

`render()` is basically just a wrapper for `drupal_render()`, except that it makes sure the element passed in is set to be shown when passed through to `drupal_render()`.

It also makes sure the element passed in is an array (which is all `drupal_render()` can accept). If it isn't, the element is return back as-is. So it provides a bit of a safety net if you like.

If for any reason you have a variable you need to render, and you don't know if it's a string or a render array, you can pass it straight through `render()` without having to test the variable type yourself.

For some real-world examples of that sort of situation there's a [list of calls to `render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/calls/render/7) you can look through.