# drupal_render() returns "Array" instead to render the content

Tags: forms

I'm using Drupal 7 and I have made a custom module in which there is this function.

```
    function product_search_by_pin_form($form, &$form_state) {
           // Provide a text field.
           $form['pin'] = array(
           '#method'=> 'POST',
           '#action' => '$come_back',
           '#title' => t('Input your PIN'),
           '#type' => 'textfield',
           '#attributes' => array('size' => '20', 'maxlength' => '20'),
           '#placeholder' => 'Type your PIN',
           '#required' => TRUE,);

           // Provide a submit button.
           $form['submit'] = array(
           '#type' => 'image_button',
           '#required' => TRUE,
           '#src' => "/images/upload/search.png",
           '#attributes' => array('id' => 'submit'),
           '#value' => 'Search',);

           return $form;
    } // END of Function
```

The form is being used from the following code.

```
    $arr = drupal_get_form('product_search_by_pin_form');
    print drupal_render($arr);
```

The problem is that Drupal displays the *Array* instead of showing the form.

How can I solve it?

**EDIT**
As asked, and after have followed suggestions but without result, please here the code of the module

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * a test file
 */

/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */


function myform_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['/examples/myform-examples'] = array(
    'title' => 'Example myform',
    'description' => 'Configuration for TEST module',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
    'page arguments' => array('product_search_by_pin_form'),
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );

  return $items;
}


/**
 * Implements hook_help().
 *
 * Displays help and module information.
 *
 * @param path 
 *   Which path of the site we're using to display help
 * @param arg 
 *   Array that holds the current path as returned from arg() function
 */

function myform_help($path, $arg) {
  switch ($path) {
    case "admin/help#myform":
      return '' . t("<b>Myform</b> to test a drupal form") . '';
      break;
  }
}


function product_search_by_pin_form($form, &$form_state) {
       // Provide a text field.
       $form['pin'] = array(
       '#method'=> 'POST',
       '#action' => '$come_back',
       '#title' => t('Input your PIN'),
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#attributes' => array('size' => '20', 'maxlength' => '20'),
       '#placeholder' => 'Type your PIN',
       '#required' => TRUE,);

       // Provide a submit button.
       $form['submit'] = array(
       '#type' => 'image_button',
       '#required' => TRUE,
       '#src' => "/images/upload/search.png",
       '#attributes' => array('id' => 'submit'),
       '#value' => 'Search',);

       return drupal_get_form($form);
} // END of Function
```

Comment: Where are you exactly printing that? It is randomly in your `.module` file?

Comment: in this moment I include this code into a node.  Once I see it working I will put it into the `.module` file

Comment: Please do it properly from a .module file so debugging is effective.

Comment: As an aside, textfields don't have `action` or `method` properties. Those are for the form only. Submit buttons can't be required either

Comment: Also, please read up on the drupal coding standards. :) You can also benefit from using the coder module.

Comment: what are your hook_menu  item properties for this route?

Comment: you have two mistakes , one  rplace `return drupal_get_form($form);` with `return $form;` and second routes in drupal 7 don't start with `/` , change `/examples/myform-examples` to `examples/myform-examples`

Comment: but `return drupal_get_form($form)` is into the third solution you gave.
PS deleting the `/`appears the title of the page with no content  (at least hte "page not found" is gone) and a bunch of errors

Comment: @TormyVanCool we are speaking about second solution. please  try the second solution as the I write for you. not add `/` and `drupal_get_form`.

Comment: @zhilevan done. It works. I didn't understand your point about Drupal_get_form(). That's why I persisted on my error.
Second solution, now, works

Comment: @TormyVanCool you're welcome, I'm here to help another drupalists. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First try Render instead of drupal_render

```
$arr = drupal_get_form('product_search_by_pin_form');
print render($arr);
```

From Clive answer on [what is the difference between render() and drupal_render()?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/66302/what-is-the-difference-between-render-and-drupal-render)

> The docs for render() explain it pretty well:
>
> This function renders an element using drupal_render(). The top level
>   element is shown with show() before rendering, so it will always be
>   rendered even if hide() had been previously used on it. render() is
>   basically just a wrapper for drupal_render(), except that it makes
>   sure the element passed in is set to be shown when passed through to
>   drupal_render().
>
> It also makes sure the element passed in is an array (which is all
>   drupal_render() can accept). If it isn't, the element is return back
>   as-is. So it provides a bit of a safety net if you like.
>
> If for any reason you have a variable you need to render, and you
>   don't know if it's a string or a render array, you can pass it
>   straight through render() without having to test the variable type
>   yourself.

and another solution is, use `drupal_get_form` as you call back function and pass your form to it as an argument. ( take a look at https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/howtos/how-to-make-a-simple-module-with-a-form-and-menu-link )

```
function YOURMODULE-NAME_menu() {
  $items = array();

  $items['examples/form-example'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
    'title' => 'Example Form', //page title
    'description' => 'A form to mess around with.',
    'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
    'page arguments' => array('product_search_by_pin_form'), //put the name of the form here
    'access callback' => TRUE
  );

  return $items;
}

function product_search_by_pin_form($form, &$form_state) {
         // Provide a text field.
       $form['pin'] = array(
       '#method'=> 'POST',
       '#action' => '$come_back',
       '#title' => t('Input your PIN'),
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#attributes' => array('size' => '20', 'maxlength' => '20'),
       '#placeholder' => 'Type your PIN',
       '#required' => TRUE,);

       // Provide a submit button.
       $form['submit'] = array(
       '#type' => 'image_button',
       '#required' => TRUE,
       '#src' => "/images/upload/search.png",
       '#attributes' => array('id' => 'submit'),
       '#value' => 'Search',);

  return $form;
}
```

and **third** is another way of implementation second solution

```
function product_search_by_pin_form($form, &$form_state) {
       // Provide a text field.
       $form['pin'] = array(
       '#method'=> 'POST',
       '#action' => '$come_back',
       '#title' => t('Input your PIN'),
       '#type' => 'textfield',
       '#attributes' => array('size' => '20', 'maxlength' => '20'),
       '#placeholder' => 'Type your PIN',
       '#required' => TRUE,);

       // Provide a submit button.
       $form['submit'] = array(
       '#type' => 'image_button',
       '#required' => TRUE,
       '#src' => "/images/upload/search.png",
       '#attributes' => array('id' => 'submit'),
       '#value' => 'Search',);

       return drupal_get_form($form);
} // END of Function
```

Comment: also render returns just the word: Array

Comment: @TormyVanCool did you try all three solutions?

Comment: You have got to get this out of a body field on a node. All three of these solutions should work.

Comment: @zhilevan yes, the first returns "array", the second: doesn't work. There is not even a page at localhost/examples/form-example. As consequence also the 3rd doesn't work

Comment: @TormyVanCool second solution is the standard way of drupal, after any changes on any hook_menu  you should clear the cache , and if you didn't any page on that url it because cache not cleared. please the cache and infrom me about the result.

Comment: @zhilevan I'm actually working on a fresh Drupal installation to avoid any issue.
I uninstalled the module, cleared the cache, installed the module. Still the second solution not working. I called the module `myform` and it contains:
`myform_info()`, `myform_help()` and `product_search_by_pin_form()`

Comment: @TormyVanCool can you add your module codes to question?

Comment: @zhilevan I edited the message and I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

Don't return `drupal_get_form()` from your function. Just return the $form variable. Your menu item is already calling `drupal_get_form()`, you don't need to from your form builder.

When calling it programmatically, use the `render()` function to turn a form array to HTML output.

Comment: Kevin is correct - your problem lies with calling drupal_get_form() twice. You don't need render() or drupal_render().

Comment: He updates the question according to my comment, in last comments I mentioned him to remove drupal_get_form from function and also remove `/` from the beginning of the route. routes not started with '/' in drupal 7.
@Jaypan : read my last comment below the question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing the form directly, You should be returning the form array. like

```
  $output['form'] = drupal_get_form('product_search_by_pin_form');
    return $output;
```

if you have to handle it seperately, You should be creating a template and print the form varibale in that temlate.

Comment: it returns always just the word "Array"